# What's the difference between (list nil) and '(nil) in Lisp?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, literals

First of all, let me say I'm a beginner in Lisp. To be honest I have been a beginner for some time now, but there are still many things I don't know well.

While I was writing [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29884737/appending-to-the-result-of-a-loop-collect-in-lisp), I came up with a strange bug in my code.

Here is a function that will return the list `(0 1 ... n)` with the list `e` appended. It uses `rplacd` along the way to keep track of the last element, to avoid a final call to `last`.

For example, `(foo 4 '(x))` returns `(0 1 2 3 4 x)`.

The "head" is stored in `a`, which is not simply `nil`, because there is only one `nil`, and never a copy of it (if I understand correctly), hence I can't simply append to `nil`.

```
(defun foo (n e)
    (let* ((a (list nil)) (tail a))
        (loop for i to n
              do (rplacd tail (setf tail (list i)))
              finally (rplacd tail (setf tail e))
              (return (cdr a)))))

(defun bar (n e)
    (let* ((a '(nil)) (tail a))
        (loop for i to n
              do (rplacd tail (setf tail (list i)))
              finally (rplacd tail (setf tail e))
              (return (cdr a)))))
```

The only difference between these functions is the `(list nil)` replaced by `'(nil)` in `bar`. While `foo` works as expected, `bar` always returns `nil`.

My initial guess is this happens because the original `cdr` of `a` is indeed `nil`, and the quoted list may be considered constant. However, if I do `(setf x '(nil)) (rplacd x 1)` I get `(nil . 1)` as expected, so I must be at least partially wrong.

Comment: It looks like `bar`'s parentheses are unbalanced.

Comment: @user2357112 Corrected. The missing closing paren was just after `'(nil)`. Sorry for this.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Common Lisp, but I believe in Scheme, anything quoted with `'` is supposed to be treated as immutable. Does that hold in Common Lisp? It looks like you're trying to mutate the thing.

Comment: @user2357112 Yes, I remember this from my past experience with Scheme. It does not *seem* to be the same in Common Lisp. But I'm cautious because I suspect my bug has something to do with this.

Comment: My other guess would be that in one version, you're getting a list with the symbol `nil` in it, and in the other version, `nil` is evaluated to an empty list. EDIT: No, it looks like the symbol `nil` evaluates to the symbol `nil`.

Comment: @user2357112 Actually, `(list nil)` and `'(nil)` represent almost the same thing. For example, they are `equal`, but not `eq` (which means they are not the same object, though they have the same "structural" contents, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/547436/whats-the-difference-between-eq-eql-equal-and-equalp-in-common-lisp)). And `nil` is a weird object, that represents both the false boolean and the empty list, and two variables set to `nil` are always `eq` (the same object), and this causes some problems when you want to initialize a list to something empty, to later update.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When evaluated, '(nil) and (list nil) produce similar lists, but the former can be considered constant when present in source code. You should not perform any destructive operations on a constant quoted list in Common Lisp. See http://l1sp.org/cl/3.2.2.3 and http://l1sp.org/cl/quote. In particular, the latter says "The consequences are undefined if literal objects (including quoted objects) are destructively modified."

Comment: This makes sense, thank you. So, to be sure, it's only thanks to *undefined consequences* if `(setf x '(nil)) (rplacd x 1)` does what I wrongly expected? Here Scheme is more friendly, since it would notify the error, IIRW.

Comment: When SBCL can detect the modification of constant data, it will issue a helpful warning and cite the applicable bits of the standard. (That's how I looked up the references for my reply.) But it can't detect all situations yet. Until then you just have to know the rule.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut :  An old Scheme FAQ says: Section 3.4 of R5RS states that it is an error to attempt to modify an immutable object, such as a literal list. Not all Schemes report this as an error though and instead do modify the literal list.

Answer (score 4):

Quoted data is considered a constant. If you have two functions:

```
(defun test (&optional (arg '(0)))
  (setf (car arg) (1+ (car arg)))
  (car arg))

(defun test2 ()
  '(0))
```

These are two functions both using the constant list `(0)` right?

1. The implementation may choose to not mutate constants:

   ```
   (test) ; ==> Error, into the debugger we go
   ```
2. The implementation can `cons` the same list twice (the reader might do that for it)

   ```
   (test2) ; ==> (0)
   (test)  ; ==> 1
   (test)  ; ==> 2
   (test)  ; ==> 3
   (test2) ; ==> (0)
   ```
3. The implementation can see it's the same and hench save space:

   ```
   (test2) ; ==> (0)
   (test)  ; ==> 1
   (test)  ; ==> 2
   (test)  ; ==> 3
   (test2) ; ==> (3)
   ```

In fact. The last two behavior might happen in the same implementation dependent on the function being compiled or not.

In CLISP both functions work the same. I also see when disassembling with SBCL that the constant actually is mutated so I wonder if perhaps it has constant folded `(cdr '(0))` at compile time and doesn't use the mutated list at all. It really doesn't matter since both are considered good "undefined" behavior.

The part [from CLHS](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/s_quote.htm) about this is very short

> The consequences are undefined if literal objects (including quoted
>   objects) are destructively modified.

Comment: Thank you. Just to be sure, if I **copy-list** a quoted list, the copy is mutable, right?

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut Yes, but only the top level since `copy-list` makes a shallow copy. Thus it does not make copies recursively of list elements in the list like [`copy-tree`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw61/CLHS/Body/f_cp_tre.htm#copy-tree) does.

Comment: One more question: in the [CLHS page](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_nconc.htm) for function **nconc**, there is an example: *(setq x '(a b c)) (setq y '(d e f)) (nconc x y)* Isn't this wrong? I mean, both x and y hold a litteral list, and x is modified by nconc.